# Append groupID newusers

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, awk, sh

I have a file with a wrong structure, which I convert to the correct structure using a while..read loop

```
userid1:john doe smith:group1
userid2:jane doe smith:group2
userid3:paul rudd :group2
```

Code so far:

```
while IFS=: read userid username; do 
        userid=`echo $username|cut -d ":" -f 1`
             echo "$userid:password:$username:/home/$userid/bin/bash";
        done <  users.txt > newusers.txt
```

Which gives me this output,

```
userid1:password123:John Doe Smith:/home/userid1/bin/bash
userid2:password123:Jane Doe Smith:/home/userid2/bin/bash
userid3:password123:Paul Rudd:/home/userid3/bin/bash
```

Now I need to append the uid (auto-generate, so blank) and the gid, not sure how to do so, I already have the groups created with 2020 and 2040.

Desired output:

```
userid1:password123::2020:John Doe Smith:/home/userid1/bin/bash
userid2:password123::2040:Jane Doe Smith:/home/userid2/bin/bash
userid3:password123::2040:Paul Rudd:/home/userid3/bin/bash
```

Cheers.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: Why does `userid1` has `2020` and `userid2` has `2040`? Where is this information stored?

Comment: `id userid1` will give you the id and groupid values.

Comment: @karafka this is previous to the creation of the user, so it has no value until then.

Comment: @KamilCuk two different groups. group1=2020, group2=2040

Comment: Ok.... so why do you read `IFS=: read userid username` and not `IFS=: read userid username group` and then `if [ group = group1 ]; then groupid=2020` and just use that in your `echo`? I mean, if you were able to write a while read loop, where are you stuck?

Comment: The script you posted wouldn't produce the output you say it does and you accepted an answer that doesn't capitalize names (paul -> Paul) like you show you want. nor does it strip the blank char off the 3rd user name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code could look like:

```
while IFS=: read -r userid username group; do 
        if [ "$group" = "group1" ]; then
           groupid=2020
         elif [ "$group" = "group2" ]; then
           groupid=2040
         else
           echo "Unknown groupid"
           do something with error.
         fi
         echo "$userid:password123::$groupid:$username:/home/$userid/bin/bash";
done <  users.txt > newusers.txt
```

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do it all

```
$ awk -F: '{gid=$3=="group1" ? "2020":"2040";print $1 FS "password123" FS FS gid \
    FS $2 FS "/home/" $1 "/bin/bash" }' ./users.txt

userid1:password123::2020:john doe smith:/home/userid1/bin/bash
userid2:password123::2040:jane doe smith:/home/userid2/bin/bash
userid3:password123::2040:paul rudd:/home/userid3/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = ":"
    gid["group1"] = 2020
    gid["group2"] = 2040
}
{ print $1, "password123", "", gid[$3], $2, "/home/" $1 "/bin/bash" }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
userid1:password123::2020:john doe smith:/home/userid1/bin/bash
userid2:password123::2040:jane doe smith:/home/userid2/bin/bash
userid3:password123::2040:paul rudd:/home/userid3/bin/bash
```

Note that the above removes the undesirable blank after `paul rudd` from your input. Now to also convert the first the letter in each name to upper case would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"
    OFS = ":"
    gid["group1"] = 2020
    gid["group2"] = 2040
}
{
    name = ""
    numParts = split($2,parts," ")
    for (i=1; i<=numParts; i++) {
        part = parts[i]
        name = (i>1 ? name " " : "") toupper(substr(part,1,1)) substr(part,2)
    }
    print $1, "password123", "", gid[$3], name, "/home/" $1 "/bin/bash"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
userid1:password123::2020:John Doe Smith:/home/userid1/bin/bash
userid2:password123::2040:Jane Doe Smith:/home/userid2/bin/bash
userid3:password123::2040:Paul Rudd:/home/userid3/bin/bash
```